# append wrapper class values if id are same

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I have a List of type wrapper class having two variables let's say col1 and col2.
I want to append all col2 values if their col1 is the same and store it as col 1 and col 2 in a new variable.
Here is the data illustration:

**Scenario 1:**
**Input:**

```
col1 col2
1      a
1      b
2      c
2      d
3      e
3      f
```

**Output:**

```
col1 col2
1 a;b;
2 c;d;
3 e;f;
```

**Scenario 2**
**Input:**

```
col1 col2
1      a
2      c
3      e
```

**Output:**

```
 col1 col2

1 a;
2 c;
3 e;
```

I am trying to achieve the same using the below code. But not able to make my way around :

```
            String val='';
            for(Integer i=1; i<=fieldListInsert.size()-1; i++){
                if(fieldListInsert[i+1].col1!= fieldListInsert[i].col1){
                    updatelist.put(fieldListInsert[i].col1,val);
                    val='';
                }else{
                    val+=fieldListInsert[i].col2+';'+fieldListInsert[i+1].col2+';';
                }
            }
```

UPDATE: missed to mention fieldListInsert is the wrapper class and updatelist is a map of type map<Id,String>
Since I couldn't explain from my data diagram I am adding image of input and required output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating new list you should use map.
Below is the code example:

```
map<Integer,list<String>> newKeyValuesMap= new map<Integer,list<String>>();
for(Integer i=0; i<=fieldListInsert.size(); i++){
    if(!newKeyValuesMap.containsKey(fieldListInsert[i].col1)){
     newKeyValuesMap.put(fieldListInsert[i].col1,new list<String>{fieldListInsert[i].col2});
    }
    else{
      newKeyValuesMap.get(fieldListInsert[i].col1).add(fieldListInsert[i].col2);
    }
}
```

You can learn more about maps [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm)

below is the updated code version:

```
map<String,String> newKeyValuesMap= new map<String,String>();
for(Integer i=0; i<=fieldListInsert.size(); i++){ 
  if(newKeyValuesMap.containsKey(fieldListInsert[i].col1)){
   String val=newKeyValuesMap.get(fieldListInsert[i].col1)+fieldListInsert[i].col2+';';
   newKeyValuesMap.put(fieldListInsert[i].col1,val);
  }
  else{
     newKeyValuesMap.put(fieldListInsert[i].col1,fieldListInsert[i].col2+';');
  }
}

List<Wrapper> wrapperList=new List<Wrapper>();
for(String str : newKeyValuesMap.keySet()){
    Wrapper wrap =new Wrapper();
    wrap.col1=str;
    wrap.col2=newKeyValuesMap.get(str);
    wrapperList.add(wrap);
}
return wrapperList;
```

Comment: I tried your code but it is throwing me "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void containsKey(String) from the type Map<Integer,List<String>>" on all the methods (get, put) used for map variable. Any idea why? I did declare the variable.

Comment: Is col1 type of String? If it is, then please replace map<Integer,list<String>>  with map<String,list<String>>

Comment: Thanks that was the issue. But as I suspected looking at your code the output is not appending col2 values its just overall converting my wrapper into map

Comment: So basically, what is happing here is, it is looping over your wrapper list and storing list of col2 for every unique col1 and then returning the map<String,List<String>>.

map is just the way to return list of col2 values for every unique col1.

Comment: That I understood but I have to append all the Map's List<String> as String separated by ';' .This I am unable to do. Example The output should be Like Map<String, String>.

Comment: Okay understood, so below what you can do :


map<String,String> newKeyValuesMap= new map<String,String>();
for(Integer i=0; i<=fieldListInsert.size(); i++){
    if(newKeyValuesMap.containsKey(fieldListInsert[i].col1)){
      String val=newKeyValuesMap.get(fieldListInsert[i].col1)+';'+fieldListInsert[i].col2;
      newKeyValuesMap.put(fieldListInsert[i].col1,val);
    }
    else{
      newKeyValuesMap.put(fieldListInsert[i].col1,fieldListInsert[i].col2);
    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124526/discussion-between-akash-and-shagun-sharma).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Maps and their feature of having distinct key

Example for your problem:

```
public with sharing class StackQuestion {

    public static Map<Integer, List<String>> processData(){
        List<Wrapper> wrap = new List<Wrapper>();
        Map<Integer, List<String>> mapToReturn = new Map<Integer, List<String>>();
        wrap.add(new Wrapper(1, 'a'));
        wrap.add(new Wrapper(1, 'b'));
        wrap.add(new Wrapper(2, 'c'));
        wrap.add(new Wrapper(2, 'd'));

        for(Wrapper wr : wrap) {
            if(mapToReturn.get(wr.col1) != null) {
                mapToReturn.get(wr.col1).add(wr.col2);
            } else {
                mapToReturn.put(wr.col1, wr.col2);
            }
        }

        return mapToReturn;

    }

    public class Wrapper {
        Integer col1;
        String col2;

        public Wrapper(Integer data1, String data2) {
            col1 = data1;
            col2 = data2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but your code logic is same as @Shagun. The col2 append is not happening

Comment: the append need to happen only for col2 where col 1 is the same
so it's more like denormalizing 1NF in DBMS terms

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, there is no error checking but it seems to fulfil your requirements:

```
public with sharing class StackQuestion {

private Map<Integer, Set<String>> valuesByIndex = new Map<Integer, Set<String>>();

public void addValue(Integer index, String value) {

    Set<String> values = getValues(index);

    if (values == null) {
        values = new Set<String>();
        valuesByIndex.put(index, values);
    }

    values.add(value);

}

public Set<String> getValues(Integer index) {
    return valuesByIndex.get(index);
}

public String getAllValuesForIndex(Integer index) {
    return String.valueOf(index) + ' ' + String.join(new List<String>(valuesByIndex.get(index)), ';');
}
```

}

And then the running code:

```
StackQuestion sq = new StackQuestion();
sq.addValue(1, 'a');
sq.addValue(1, 'b');
sq.addValue(2, 'c');
sq.addValue(2, 'd');
sq.addValue(3, 'e');
sq.addValue(3, 'f');
System.debug(sq.getAllValuesForIndex(1));
System.debug(sq.getAllValuesForIndex(2));
System.debug(sq.getAllValuesForIndex(3));
```

Which outputs:

|USER_DEBUG|[10]|DEBUG|1 a;b
|USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|2 c;d
|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|3 e;f